# OR short circuit in javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, short-circuiting

The OR short-circuit is not working the way I think its supposed to. Ofcourse I am doing something wrong but can't figure it out. Please HELP! its driving me crazy

I am trying to solve the problem of merging two linked lists

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    let root = new ListNode(-1);
    
    function recList(node, l1, l2) {
        if(!l1 && !l2) {
            return;   
        }
        let smallerNode;
       
        if(!l1) {
            smallerNode = l2;  
         }
        if(!l2) {
            smallerNode = l1;   
        }
        
        
        smallerNode = smallerNode || (l1.val <= l2.val) ? l1 : l2; // this throws an error that cant evaluate .val of null as l1 is null
        
        // however this works just fine
        // if(!smallerNode) {
        //    smallerNode = (l1.val <= l2.val) ? l1 : l2;
        // }
        
        node.next = smallerNode;
        if(smallerNode === l1) {
            l1 = l1.next;
            
        } else {
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        
        recList(smallerNode, l1, l2);
    }
    
    recList(root, l1, l2);
    
    return root.next;
};
```

Comment: Take a look at [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)

Comment: its left to right ..and i dont think thats the problem here .. so the issue is arising when `(l1.val <= l2.val) ? l1 : l2` gets evaluated in `smallerNode = smallerNode || (l1.val <= l2.val) ? l1 : l2;` even when `smallerNode` exists .... in this case `smallerNode` gets evaluated to l2 before entering the conditional which has a value .. try and run it here https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

Comment: You didn't take a look at the linked table?

Comment: `6 Logical OR left-to-right … || … ` right ?  so when left expression resolves to a value right is not even evaluated... as an example   console.log( let x = true || somenonstringjibberish) will resolve to x = true even without throwing an error